# Load wordpress shortcode with a button?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, deferred-loading

**Question:**

Is it possible to load a WordPress shortcode on demand, e.g. with a button?

**Explanation:**

I have a gallery plugin, it has a shortcode. Unfortunately, the plugin does NOT use image defer mechanism on page load. So it has too many image requests that hurt speed ranking.

**Is this idea possible:**

I want a "load gallery" button. When it's pressed, the gallery **shortcode is loaded**. Any recommendation / article / key concepts is welcomed. I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Yes, it is possible and requires just a small amount of code. The main idea is to use an AJAX request to load the page the shortcode would be in and bypass the normal WordPress template processing and replace it with the evaluation of your shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom buttons to the editor -> https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons