# WordPress load PHP plugin on demand with jQuery / AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I need to load a WordpPress plugin shortcode with jQuery / Ajax / PHP on demand, *ONLY* when we press a button. This is what I tried:

**1) I have an HTML code with a button and a DIV:**

```
<a href="#" class="LoadBtn">Load Gallery Plugin</a>
<div id="PhotoGrid">Plugin shortcode should be loaded here</div>
```

**2) When I press the button, the following jQuery code runs. This communicates with a PHP file and tries to "insert" a shortcode into the DIV:**

```
$(function() {
  $('.LoadBtn').on('click', function() {

    var url = "http://localhost:8888/studio/ajax.php";
    $.post(url, function(data) {
        $("#PhotoGrid").html(data).show();
    });

  });
});
```

**3) PHP code:**

```
echo do_shortcode('[wonderplugin_gridgallery id=1]');
```

**But I run into an error.**
In the jQuery code, there is a *html(data)* string. Maybe that's the problem as the shortcode is not an hmtl but a full plugin code? I am new to PHP, what and how to write?

**Error message that I get in console:**

- send @   jquery.js?ver=1.11.3:5
- send @   jquery.js?ver=1.11.3:5
- ajax @   jquery.js?ver=1.11.3:5
- m.(anonymous function)   @   jquery.js?ver=1.11.3:5
- (anonymous)  @   my-custom.js
- dispatch @   jquery.js?ver=1.11.3:4
- r.handle @   jquery.js?ver=1.11.3:4

Comment: Just to confirm, the PHP code was taken from the plugin developer's website.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between server side and client side code. You can only load in PHP Plugins with a reload, or let the server generate the parts of the side seperately

Comment: So what I want to achieve is not possible? I wanted to load in the gallery only if the user requests it - to speed up the page.

Comment: Can you generate the Gallery on it's own without any other HTML code around it?

Comment: with a simple shortcode yes. If I put this anywhere on the page, it will be loaded in:[wonderplugin_gridgallery id=1]

Comment: But will that work if you put only this into a PHP-File? Otherwise, why not reload with an appropriate # in the URL to the part of the site the user was on and a get parameter like `g=1` and load the plugin based on this parameter?

Comment: Why are you using `$.post()`? Are you sending data to the PHP page you are loading? Also, is the referenced PHP page loading Wordpress, or are you just attempting to echo out `do_shortcode()` in a PHP file by itself?

Comment: Benji - It's just an attempt to echo a do_shortcode in a small PHP file, nothing else. The WordPress page is already loaded in. Maybe it's not possible what I want to achieve: to load a WordPress plugin on demand when the visitor clicks on a button. I wrote $.post() because that's what I saw in an online tutorial. It works if the content in the PHP file is just a simple text, but it doesn't work if it's a plugin short code. I am totally new to PHP.

Comment: If you are referencing a PHP file that only contains that shortcode, it won't work. You'll need to [load Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47049/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress-files) first to use these functions. Also I might suggest using `$.load()` instead.

Comment: Thank you! At least I don't waste another day on it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49453524/load-wordpress-shortcode-with-a-button) I surmise that your objective is to improve speed ranking by deferring the load of the gallery. This can be done quite easily with a small amount of PHP code - ~ 25 lines but from your comments I surmise that you have not yet acquired the skill level to do this. However there is an ugly, inefficient trick you can use to circumvent this problem. The [jQuery .load() function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) can be used to load just a fragment of an HTML document.

```
$("#PhotoGrid").load( "<url of page with gallery shortcode>", "<jQuery selector of the gallery HTML" );
```

The server will send the complete page from which the jQuery .load() function will extract the HTML of the gallery using the jQuery selector and insert it into the "#PhotoGrid" element. This is slightly inefficient as the server builds the complete page and only the gallery shortcode fragment is necessary. To be clear you now need two pages an initial page with the call to the jQuery .load() function and your original page with the gallery shortcode. Your original page is never displayed directly but used as a source from which the HTML of the gallery shortcode can be extracted.

In fact, since the original page is used only as a source for the gallery HTML you can make this more efficient by removing the header, footer and sidebar by using a custom template and having a post content with only the gallery shortcode. You really only need the environment where the shortcode will be evaluated correctly and nothing else. If you do this I suspect this will execute almost as efficient as the solution I suggest next.

Note that this is not as inefficient as loading a page twice as the .js and .css files are loaded only once by the initial page. It is also necessary that the initial page load all the needed .css and .js files as the second load will not load any .css or .js files.

There is one caveat to this technique. If the original HTML page was doing additional processing of the gallery in a $(document).ready() handler then since this handler runs only on the initial load of the document you will also need to execute any necessary code in that handler after the load of the gallery.

If you want to do this more efficiently you need to write some tricky PHP code. The main idea is to use an AJAX request to load the page the shortcode would be in and bypass the normal WordPress template processing using the action 'template_redirect' and replace it with the evaluation of your shortcode. Note that this is not an 'wp_ajax ...' action as that processing will not be done in the context of a post.

Comment: Thanks Magenta, this is a really detailed help and a good trick. I hope it will help others too. It also gave me an idea: the gallery could sit on a subdomain on a totally stripped down WordPress page and load in on demand into an iframe..? Although your trick would make sure that only the required DIV is used. I hope to learn PHP and use the more efficient method later on.. but for now.. I stick to iframe or your idea.

Comment: Since an iframe is really a totally different page to the browser it will load all the .css and .js files again. Although the browser can retrieve these from the browser cache and not need to make another request to the server it will still need to re-parse them - a unnecessary duplication of effort. This is of course assuming that the child and parent pages are using the same .css files and .js files. So, to be truly efficient you need to customise your parent and child .css and .js files to exactly what they are using.

Comment: An advantage to using an iframe is it will avoid the $(document).ready() handler problem. The disadvantage is it is heavy in the sense that it adds another context (DOM) for the browser to hold.

Comment: Magenta, so your initial jQuery suggestion works better than the iframe. (iframe is producing error with the image lightbox). However, the jQuery method - while it works OK - produces a yellow warning in the console. I wonder if you have any idea what this could mean, can I safely just ignore it? Console message: " [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/." Thanks!

Comment: No, Synchronous XMLHttpRequest are very bad as it can make the page non responsive to the user. I am somewhat surprised as I did not think .load() was implemented as a synchronous call - doesn't seem right to me. Anyway as .load() is just a convenience function for get() followed by a call to $() on the response I would try and replace the .load() with that. But, something is not right here as I don't think .load() uses a synchronous call.

Comment: Since, I really did not think .load() was implemented with a synchronous call I ran some code that uses .load() on the Chrome browser and it does not show that error message.

Comment: Also tested with Firefox browser and again no warning. .load() should be implemented with an asynchronous call. Since, .load() and get() are just convenience functions for ajax() you can replace everything with a call to ajax(). The nice thing about ajax() is that it is low level and you can explicily specify the async mode.